# How to set middle half Image to bottom navigation bar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to set an image to the middle of the bottom navigation bar which looks it attached with bottom view.

[image: Desired Image]

Comment: Please share image of what you want to achieve

Comment: I already shared image of the bottom view.

Comment: What do you want to do with that view?

Comment: Use stack for above(as per design) Image and put position to particular widget
or use floating button https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49299457/how-to-add-button-to-bottom-navigation-bar-which-hang-out-above-flutter

Comment: Share the code so its easy to handle as per your code

Answer (score 3):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can use

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
...
bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
    shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
```

For detail you can reference https://proandroiddev.com/flutter-how-to-using-bottomappbar-75d53426f5af

working demo

[image]

code snippet

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget { 
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(        
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: BottomAppBarPage(),
    );
  }
}

class BottomAppBarPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Bottom App Bar')),
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 4.0,
        child: new Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: () {},
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```