# how to create navigation bar in flutter like this image?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

[image][image]

How can I create this type of bottomnavigation bar in flutter

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.add)),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.mode_comment_outlined))
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49299457/how-to-add-button-to-bottom-navigation-bar-which-hang-out-above-flutter

Comment: it may be help you:
https://morioh.com/p/09febfa395b8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way.

```
return Scaffold(
      body: _buildBody(),
      bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottomBar(),
      extendBody: true,
      floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
      floatingActionButton: Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

////

```
Widget _buildBottomBar() {
    return Container(
      height: 60,
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, left: 50, right: 50),
      child: Material(
        elevation: 0.0,
        color: Colors.blue,
        shape: StadiumBorder(),
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          elevation: 0,
          onTap: (index) {
            _currentIndex = index;
            setState(() {});
          },
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          showSelectedLabels: false,
          showUnselectedLabels: false,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: ""),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.mode_comment_outlined), label: "")
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

**Output:** [image: custom_bottom_bar]

Comment: I used your code thanks but the borders are not rounded shape even though you have given 30 why? how to make borders are rounded?

Comment: Let me attach the output of the above code.

Comment: ok but tell me how to make borders rounded

Comment: `shape: StadiumBorder(),`

Comment: `shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),`  Remove this line and replace it with `shape: StadiumBorder(),`

Comment: I did but there is no effect in borders

Comment: child: Material(
      elevation: 50.0,
      shape: const StadiumBorder(),
      child: BottomNavigationBar(
        //elevation: 5.0,
        onTap: (index) {

        },

        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home), label: ""),

Comment: `backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,` Add this one in your code.

Comment: set `BottomNavigationBar` bg color as `transparent`. Refer my code.

Comment: got it but check the image I posted, there is a black layer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242263/discussion-between-dholahardik-and-mohan).